# Is there an endpoint to get Google Root Certificates list for verifying hardware-backed key pairs?

Tags: security, hardware, certificates

I would like to verify a hardware-backed key pair in my Java backend service.

According to the [Verifying hardware-backed key pairs with Key Attestation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-key-attestation#root_certificate) page, I need to verify the attestation object against the Google Root Certificates list.

I don't want to hardcode this list in my codebase as it makes it less flexible and I'd have to keep it up to date manually.

Is there an endpoint to fetch this list dynamically? I see a similar endpoint for the [Certificate Revocation Status List](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-key-attestation#certificate_status)

Comment: Also posted on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73557927/2821954

Comment: As this question is only about hardware verification root CAs (which are used on the server side) it is clearly a development question and thus OT here.